# Synchronous request with Websockets

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket

I can send and receive messages from server on websockets. I need to write a function that will send data to the server and is awaiting a response from the server and then return it as a result of a function.

Send:

```
ws.send('my_message_to_server');
```

Receive (it's a event):

```
ws.bind('message', function(message) {
console.log(message);
});
```

My function:

```
function request(message){
ws.send(message);
    //How wait for receive???
    return response;
}
```

Comment: You can't make a synchronous function for something asynchronous. Busy waiting is yuck, and JavaScript does not support it. Why would you want to do so? Have a look at promises.

Comment: @Bergi actually you can. take a look at my answer below. just create a simple queue, no busy waiting in that example :)

Comment: @RonanDejhero: No, your function is not synchronous. It does use an asynchronous callback, as every socket listener needs to.

Comment: **There is a script: https://npmjs.com/package/ws-sync-request**

Answer (score 23):

There's a neat way I used in some online game a while ago, but you will need to change stuff on the server side as well !

1st make a function to send the data

```
var socketQueueId = 0;
var socketQueue = {};

function sendData(data, onReturnFunction){
    socketQueueId++;
    if (typeof(returnFunc) == 'function'){
        // the 'i_' prefix is a good way to force string indices, believe me you'll want that in case your server side doesn't care and mixes both like PHP might do
        socketQueue['i_'+socketQueueId] = onReturnFunction;
    }
    jsonData = JSON.stringify({'cmd_id':socketQueueId, 'json_data':data});
    try{
        webSocket.send(jsonData);
        console.log('Sent');
    }catch(e){
        console.log('Sending failed ... .disconnected failed');
    }
}
```

Then in the server side, when processing the request, you should send the cmd_id back to the client with the response

```
webSocket.onmessage = function(e) {

    try{
        data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    }catch(er){
        console.log('socket parse error: '+e.data);
    }

    if (typeof(data['cmd_id']) != 'undefined' && typeof(socketQueue['i_'+data['cmd_id']]) == 'function'){
        execFunc = socketQueue['i_'+data['cmd_id']];
        execFunc(data['result']);
        delete socketQueue['i_'+data['cmd_id']]; // to free up memory.. and it is IMPORTANT thanks  Le Droid for the reminder
        return;
    }else{
        socketRecieveData(e.data);
    }
}
```

and create a function to handle all other types of returns:

```
socketRecieveData(data){
    //whatever processing you might need
}
```

so now simply if you want to send some data for the server and wait for response for that specific data you simple do:

```
sendData('man whats 1+1', function(data){console.log('server response:');console.log(data);});
```

Comment: Wow, really a good Idea! It took me some time to understand but sending the callback to the server and jsonify it back to the client is brilliant.

Comment: I was looking for this exact solution being too lazy to reinvent the wheel. Very elegant and flexible. 'i_' is optional as dictionaries work with int too. You could add the following after execFunc call to free up memory:
delete socketQueue['i_'+data['cmd_id']];

Comment: What if you need to access variabes that are in context/scope of where you would call this? As I understand it ´function(data){}´ is called out of the scope of webSocket.onmessage and makes this problematic

Answer (score 3):

When you create a websocket, you usually add a onmessage callback function to the socket which is called whenever the client receives data from the server.

```
 var socket = new WebSocket("ws://example.com:8000/websocketapp.php");  
 socket.onmessage = function(msg){
      alert('The server says: ' + msg);
 }
```

A function which blocks until the server responds is a bad idea conceptually, because it means that the script execution will hang until the answer from the server came in. When the server is busy and the network latency is high, this can take several seconds. For that reason it is better to work with callback functions (functions which are called when an event happens).

When you can guarantee that you only send one request at a time to the server, you can just change the socket.onmessage function to a function which processes the servers response and acts on it:

```
 socket.onopen = function() {
    socket.send("What's your name?");
    socket.onmessage = function(message) {
        alert("The server says its name is " + message); 
        socket.send("What is the answer to life, the universe and everything?");
        socket.onmessage = function(msg){
             alert("The server says the answer is: " + msg);
        }
     }
 }
```

(By the way: I wrote the request before setting the reply handler for better readability. It would be better to do it the other way around: set the reply handler first and then send the request. This is important for the unlikely but not impossible case that the server responds so fast that the handler wasn't set up yet).

But when you have multiple parallel requests and you need to find out which request the server is referring to, you will need something better. You could, for example, have an onmessage function which identifies the message and then forwards each message to a specialized message handler function.

Comment: You probably mean `socket.send()`?

Comment: what if the server "PUSHES" some information back to the client whenever something happens on the server side ? how will this code work ? it won't !

Comment: @RonanDejhero That was not the scope of the question. But when you would add this to the above scenario, it would be equivalent to what is described in the last paragraph. The server needs to prefix each message with type-information so that the client knows how to handle it.

Comment: what i meant, you send some data to the server, the server takes too long to respond (some very long operation) and you need the results, but meanwhile you send another request to the server (and also need the results), then the server sends reply for your second request, after a while it finishes the long operation and send the results back to you, how will you identify which response to which request?. your example basically connects, sends data and awaits response, if you open a connection for each request then whats the use of websocks? you can use ajax instead

Answer (score 2):

You should use some sort of RPC protocol on top of WebSockets. I suggest you take a look at [WAMP](http://wamp.ws/) which is a WebSocket sub-protocol that adds RPC and PUB/SUB semantics. It includes a client library which abstracts the async connection to some extent by giving you a promise based API.

Here is an example:

```
var wsuri = "ws://localhost:9000";

ab.connect(wsuri, function (session) {
    session.call("http://example.com/simple/calc#add", 23, 7).then(
        function (res) {
            console.log("got result: " + res);
        },
        function (error, desc) {
            console.log("error: " + desc);
        }
    );
});
```

There are a number of server-side implementations for this.

Answer (score 2):

WebSocket is like TCP, it's just a transport layer. What you need is to run a protocol on top of webSocket. The protocol takes care of creating the correlations between messages for you. You may want to take a look at AMQP, which is the most extensive and complete open protocol for real time asynchronous messaging. See for example https://github.com/dansimpson/amqp-js for a simple AMQP client JS library.

I don't know what type of server you are using, but AMQP will give you the most flexibility as there is a lot of support for AMQP across many platforms. There are also simple AMQP message broker implementations. If your server is Java, then you will want to look at JMS. in which case you will need a more elaborate but robust JMS broker.

Comment: TCP actually involves a response from the other end for every single request you file, which makes it more like AJAX than WebSocket. UDP is the protocol you are thinking of - you throw stuff in the abyss and you pray the other end is receiving it = WebSocket. I agree with the rest of your comment, but WebSocket is not like TCP, its emulating UDP on top of TCP.

Answer (score 1):

you can write promises-based RPC wrappers for WebSocket:

```
const ws = new WebSocket(...);

ws.receive = () => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        ws.onmessage = (message) => {
            return resolve(message.data);
        }

        ws.onerror = (error) => {
            return reject(error);
        }
   });
}

ws.echo = async function () {
    ws.send('echo');

    return await ws.receive();
}
```

And use it like this:

```
console.log(await ws.echo());
```

or

```
ws.echo().then((response) => {console.log(response);});
```

PS: I omitted ws.onopen for the sake of clarity...

PS: you can arrange things to have both: RPC calls and events.

Answer (score 0):

I think the project [WebSockets-Callback](https://github.com/aidv/websockets-callback) would be easier to use

```
wscb.send({cmd: 'Hello server!'},
    function(response){
        //do something...
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There [is a ligthweight module for nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws-sync-request), which does **synchronous WS calls** (similar to `fetch`) :

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const WsSyncRequest = require('ws-sync-request');
var WSR_instance;
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:33479');

ws.on('open', async ()=> {
    WSR_instance = new WsSyncRequest(ws);
}); 

...
// then anywhere you can use:
console.log (  await WSR_instance.fetchSync({"mykey": "myValue"}, 5000) );
```