# how to use websocket like an api

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have websocket connection between client(browser) & server.

Problem is, sometimes I request a data through websocket.

But since websocket works like an event, I cannot manage my code efficiently.

I can send websocket message in a function but then I have to listen and handle it on the event listener.

Below is example.

```js
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://whatever");

function handleClickBtn() {
  ws.send('request something');
  // cannot get response here
}

ws.onmessage = function (event) {
  console.log(`response comes here: ${event.data}`);
}
```

It seems harder to maintain my code since you have to jump between request and response.
If I've used REST API, it would been easier with async/await syntax.

What kind of technique can be used here?

Comment: WebSockets are a two-way data channel, there's no such thing as a response in websocket land (unless you specifically code it as such, something like `{ "requestId": 32424, "data": "Hello, World!" }`). You might be able to find a library that does this automatically

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Synchronous request with Websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417000/synchronous-request-with-websockets)

Comment: Also: [WebSocket request-response subprotocol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10882370)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to think in async terms and indeed handle many potential in-flight requests at the same time. To be able to do this, you will need to be able to relate the incoming responses to requests you sent previously. For example, you could add random ids to your requests, and the response to it will contain the same id. E.g.:

Request:

```
[82512903521, "fetch-data", "param1", "param2"]
```

Response:

```
[82512903521, {"some": "returned", "data": ...}]
```

Then internally you keep a list of request ids you sent, together with an appropriate callback function which you'll trigger when the corresponding response returns. E.g. something like:

```
const requests = {};

function request(callback, ...params) {
    const id = randomId();
    ws.send([id, ...params])
    requests[id] = callback;
}

ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    const [id, data] = event.data;
    requests[id](data);
}
```

There are existing protocols and libraries that implement this kind of this, for example [WAMP](https://wamp-proto.org).